# Excel, copying cell between sheet based on criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to copy cells from one sheet to the other based on another cell.

If cell column D from Sheet 1 contains the text copy the cell from column A,B,C & F but above the row that corresponds the cell that contains that text

example
SHEET 1

| DATE | JEV# | ACCOUNT | CODE | DEBIT | CREDIT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell1 | Cell2 | Cell 3 | 1020 | Cell 5 | Cell 6 |
| Cell7 | Cell8 | Cell 9 | 1010 | Cell11 | Cell12 |

another sheet
`1010`

| DATE | JEV# | ACCOUNT | DEBIT | CREDIT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 | Cell 5 | Cell 6 |

Is this possible?
Thank you.

I tried advance filter, but it only copies the corresponding rows containing the certain text. i want to copy the cell above or below it.

Answer (score 2):

You need `FILTER()` function.

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A2:F3,Sheet1!D2:D3=J1)
```

[image]